# Extract alphanumeric string after matching pattren

Tags: regex, rex

Need help to extract those productIDs (**XA363636363633**) which printed as REGISTER_NOT_FOUND in log . These porductIDs will change

> {"line":"2019-10-05 03:58:11.627 ERROR [xxx-csscsc0sssscs-xxxx] 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.u.f.b.s.registryImpl  : \u003c\u003c\u003c registryImpl  : registerInformation(): caught NnaException REGISTER_NOT_FOUND productId XA363636363633 requestDate 2020-07-24"

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your code so we can help. Also, use the formatting tools built into the editor to format your code properly.

Comment: Have you had any success / issues with this problem yet?

Answer (score 0):

`REGISTER_NOT_FOUND productId (\w+)`

This will start at `REGISTER_NOT_FOUND productId` and will then capture the next string of words (alphanumerics) up to the first non-word character.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/9ykAGg/1/)